# Prestashop integrate javascript to custom page

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have created a custom page in Prestashop 1.7.X by using an own controller. How can I load a custom javascript file?

```
<?php
class MyPageControllerCore extends FrontController{
    public $php_self = 'mypage';
    public $ssl = true;

    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('mypage');
    }   

    public function setMedia(){
        parent::setMedia();
        $this->context->controller->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'about_us.js');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard way:

1- Generate new module that has frontController

2- Load your custom javascript file from your module

```
<?php
class ModulenameMypageModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'mypage';
    public $ssl = true;

    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('mypage.tpl');
    }   

    public function setMedia(){
        parent::setMedia();
        $this->context->controller->addJS(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'/views/js/about_us.js');
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the JS into the root of my theme directory /themes/xy/... and used _THEME_MODULE_DIR_.'/about_us.js', but the JS is not loaded (I have a console.log in it)

Comment: I say again: "your way is not recommended and you should not add pages manually to PrestaShop". But if you insist: You have to put your js files on "themes\Your-theme-name\assets\js" folder

Comment: But how should I add pages to prestashop? Of course I can add them via the CMS function, but this would mean that I have to either use a predefined CSS or write a module for each page